# How to show the vertical image into horizontal manner using HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, image, css

I've one small image displayed along the right edge of the screen. Actually that image is vertical but I want to display it horizontally. How should I achieve this using HTML and CSS?

For your reference following is the screen shot of the page which contains the vertical "Contact" image on right edge bottom side.
[image: The page image containing Contact sticker at bottom of the screen vertically]

Can someone please help me in it?
Following is the code I tried for the vertical position it currently has :
**HTML Code :**

```
<div id="new_button_1">
        <a href="#" >
          <img src="http://www.yourdomain.com/contact.jpeg" alt="" pagespeed_url_hash="3893298907" border="0" align="middle" height="89" width="33">
        </a>
    </div>
```

**CSS code :**

```
#new_button_1 {
  width: 33px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 85%;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 7;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS3 rotation

```
transform: rotate(90deg);
```

Comment: Can I use as follows : #new_button_1 {
  width: 33px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 85%;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 7; 
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
Will it work?

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason to use an image for such a simple button.

Let's create this with simple CSS:

[image: Screenshot]

By default, of course, it is not rotated. You can rotate it with:

```
transform: rotate(-90deg)
```

[image: Rotated]

and you can fix it to the same position it currently is using the same CSS and `transform-origin: 100% 100%` so the rotation is made on the right hand and bottom side and will line up with the viewport.

#### Further Reading on the MDN

- The [transform property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)
- The [transform-origin property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)

#### Working Examples

```css
a {
  background: #FCD033;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.rotate {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  display: inline-block;
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 80%;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 7;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 100% 100%; 
  /*x-offset y-offset = (right hand side and bottom to line up with viewport edge)*/
}
```

```html
<h2>Not Rotated</h2>
<a href="#">Contact</a>

<h2>Rotated</h2>
<a href="#" class="rotate">Contact</a>

<h2>Fixed (bottom right)</h2>
<a href="#" class="fixed">Contact</a>
```